Question on Heaviside function
I encountered this problem while solving a statistical mechanics question (physics) but the question is related to math so I thought I posted it here.
The context. Finding the number of states $\phi(E)$ with the Heaviside function $\Phi$ of an ideal gas filled of $N$ ultrarelativistic particles in a volume $V$ and energy $E$, the hamiltonian and the potential of the box $\Phi_V$ is, respectively: $$H=\sum_{i=1}^N (c|\vec{p_i}|+\Phi_V(\vec r_i))$$
$$\Phi_V(\vec r_i)=\begin{cases}
0\ \text{ if } \vec{r_i} \text{ inside box}\\
\infty \text{ if } \vec{r_i} \text{ outside box}
\end{cases}$$
The problem. We can find the number of states as such:
$$\phi(E)=\frac{1}{h^{3N}}\int \prod_{i=1}^N d\vec{r}_i d\vec{p}_i \Theta\left(E-H(\vec r,\vec p)\right)$$ $$\phi(E)=\frac{1}{h^{3N}}\int \prod_{i=1}^N d\vec{r}_i d\vec{p}_i \Theta\left[E-\sum_{i=1}^N (c|\vec p_i|  +\Phi_V(\vec r_i))\right]$$
1st doubt. Then how come you can apparently from the solution, do the following, take the $\Phi_V (\vec r_i)$ out or something and separate both integrals:
$$\phi(E)=\frac{1}{h^{3N}} \int \prod_{i=1}^N d\vec r_i \int \prod_{i=1}^N d\vec p_i \Theta\left[E-\sum_{i=1}^N c|\vec p_i|\right]$$
That is my first doubt, we then can use $\int \prod_{i=1}^N d\vec r_i = V^{N}$ as usual, and then now for the second doubt, we use the following substitution $|\vec P_i|=\frac{|\vec p_i|c}{E}$ and then $dp_i = \frac{E}{c} dP_i$ that will get later raised to $N$ so we get: $$\phi(E)=\frac{V^{N}}{h^{3N}} \int \left(\frac{E}{c}\right)^N \prod_{i=1}^N d\vec P_i \Theta\left[E-E\sum_{i=1}^N |\vec P_i| \right]$$
2nd doubt. Now my final second doubt is what they do with the Heaviside function again. They somehow pull out the $E$ factor inside the Heaviside function as if nothing happened:
$$\phi(E)=\frac{V^{N}}{h^{3N}} \int \left(\frac{E}{c}\right)^N \prod_{i=1}^N d\vec P_i \Theta\left[1-\sum_{i=1}^N |\vec P_i| \right]$$
With the purpose of using this as a given integral but that's just out of the scope of my doubt. How did they erase the $E$ like that? Is it a property of the Heaviside function that I don't know?

When you say doubt do you mean question?

@Aruralreader, by now, I've become accustomed to students in/from India saying "doubt" when most people in the U.S. or UK would say "question"... It was off-putting for a while, because it possibly suggested skepticism, etc., to US-English ears. :)

@Aruralreader yes, my bad I didn't know it wasn't a thing, I'm spanish so
